# How to disable/enable all products in commerce?

Tags: commerce

The [Commerce Backoffice module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_backoffice) allows to delete all selected products from the list. But how about to change the status for all products or for the selected ones?

Comment: It's one dependency is [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) so you can try and write a custom action plugin for it?

Comment: I hoped that there is a magic module (as allways) that will save my time. But it seems I have to dig into it on my own. Here is what I found about VBO and Rules to solve it:
[link](https://drupalcommerce.org/videos/tutorials/power-rules-views-bulk-operations-and-commerce)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will take just a few steps to create a view for your commerce product
fields values manipulation:

- add a new View:

  - "show group" set to Commerce Product "of type" - type of
         you commerce product, you want to change fields values;
  - "display format" set to "Table";
  - press "Continue & Edit";
- In "fields"  group add "Bulk operations:Commerce Product" field:

  - set checked "Modify entity values " in "Bulk operations" group;
  - press "Apply" button;

That are the main settings for your operation view. Just add fields and filters whatever you want.
Save your view and use it for change field values using bulk operations.

Comment: Thanks guys, just want to add some details: 
1.Backoffice has a views called "All Product variations" so you don't need to create a new one.

Comment: Yes, but this view (in my commerce_k...) only with one "Delete" option. But you want to change field values)